# Android Firebase Generating Likes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, java-8

I am working on an project somewhat it is same like an instagram but ,i am not getting how to mange likes when someone like the post then we can use transaction to count＋＋ the likes but when if a user again see the post how to know that the user has already like the post and make the like button in active state？

Answer (score 0):

You could store the liked posts for the user.

Either by storing them at the user:

```
users/{userId}/likes/{postId} = true
```

Or by storing them at a separate location:

```
likes/{userId}/{postId} = true
```

You could also store them at the post itself:

```
posts/{postId}/likedBy/{userId} = true
```

Thinking about it, I think the last option would probably be best as you could set the value in the same transaction as the `count++` one.